# Microsoft Graph - Grant_Type client_credentials calendarview - Access is denied. Check credentials and try again

Tags: azure, powershell, microsoft-graph-api

I am using PowerShell to get Calendar events from MS Graph.

Grant Type: client_credentials

```
$clientId = "xxx"
$tenantName = "xxx"
$clientSecret = "xxx"
$resource = "https://graph.microsoft.com/"
$ReqTokenBody = @{
Grant_Type    = "client_credentials"
Scope         = "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"
client_Id     = $clientID
Client_Secret = $clientSecret
} 
$TokenResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$TenantName/oauth2/v2.0/token" -Method POST -Body $ReqTokenBody
```

Grant Type: Password

```
$clientID = "xxx"
$tenantName = "xxx"
$ClientSecret = "xxx"
$Username = "xxx@xxx.com"
$Password = "xxx"

$ReqTokenBody = @{
Grant_Type    = "Password"
client_Id     = $clientID
Client_Secret = $clientSecret
Username      = $Username
Password      = $Password
Scope         = "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"
} 
$TokenResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$TenantName/oauth2/v2.0/token" -Method POST -Body $ReqTokenBody
```

Get Calendar Events:

```
$apiUrl = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/xxxxxxxxxx/calendarview?startdatetime=$mystartdate1&enddatetime=$myenddate1&orderby=start/DateTime ASC&top=100"
$Data = Invoke-RestMethod -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $($Tokenresponse.access_token)"} -Uri $apiUrl -Method Get
$Groups = ($Data | select-object Value).Value
#$Groups | Format-Table subject, start -AutoSize
$Groups | Select-Object -Property subject, Start, End
```

If I authenticate by Password Grant Type then it displays the results.
However if I authenticate by Client Credentials Grant Type then it throws following error:

```
Invoke-RestMethod : {
  "error": {
    "code": "ErrorAccessDenied",
    "message": "Access is denied. Check credentials and try again.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "cc111097-c8c2-4a35-af21-52cbbced33b7",
      "date": "2019-11-29T09:37:51"
    }
  }
}
At line:10 char:9
+ $Data = Invoke-RestMethod -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $($Token ...
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand
```

With the Client Credentials Grant Type I have no problem getting results from

```
$apiUrl = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/"
$apiUrl = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups'
$apiUrl = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/devicemanagement/manageddevices"
```

Am I doing something wrong or the client credentials authentication cannot pull the calendar events.

Comment: What permissions have you given the app? Specifically, what application permissions have you granted on MS Graph API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using the client credential flow to get the access token for Microsoft Graph, the `Application permission` in your AD App -> `API permissions` is needed.

But in this case, the `Application permission` is not supported for the [`List calendarView`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-list-calendarview?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) API. Without this permission, the token you got will not be able to call this API successfully.

[image]